# Linked list implementation, manipulation, and testing in C

Tags: beginner, c, linked-list

This is a beginner's attempt at implementing a linked list in C. Please read the code and provide recommendations. I do not want to limit the reader's benevolence to only these questions, but my specific questions are as follows.

- Am I treating errors, exit codes, and warning messages appropriately?
- How can I improve my testing methodology (which is currently just to write print statements and manually check them)? In particular, what's a good way of checking that deleteList is working?
- Is this code allocating and freeing memory in a responsible manner?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    typedef struct node {
        int val;
        struct node* next;
    } node_t;
    
    //printList
    void printList(node_t* head) {
        if (head) {
            node_t* current = head;
            while (current != NULL) {
                printf("%d\n", current->val);
                current = current->next;
            }
            printf("\n");
            return;
        }
        printf("Cannot print an empty list.");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    //addAtEnd
    void addAtEnd(node_t* head, int val) {
        if (head) {
            node_t* current = head;
            while (current->next != NULL) {
                current = current->next;
            }
            current->next = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
            if (current->next) {
                current->next->next = NULL;
                current->next->val = val;
            }
            return;
        }
        printf("Cannot add to NULL.");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    //addAtStart
    void addAtStart(node_t** head, int val) {
        if (*head) {
            node_t* new_node = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
            if (new_node) {
                new_node->next = *head;
                new_node->val = val;
            }
            *head = new_node;
            return;
        }
        printf("Cannot add to NULL.");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    //addAtIndex
    void addAtIndex(node_t** head, int val, int n) {
        if (*head) {
            if (n == 0) {
                addAtStart(head, val);
                return;
            }
            int i;
            node_t* current = *head;
            node_t* next_node = (*head)->next;
            for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                if (current->next == NULL) {
                    printf("Index out of bounds.");
                    exit(1);
                }
                current = current->next;
                next_node = next_node->next;
            }
            node_t* new_node = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
            if (new_node) {
                new_node->next = next_node;
                new_node->val = val;
                current->next = new_node;
                return;
            }
        }
        printf("Cannot add to NULL.");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    //removeAtEnd
    int removeAtEnd(node_t* head) {
        if (head) {
            if (head->next == NULL) {
                printf("WARNING: Removing the list's only element. Further use of this list's identifier will result in unintended effects.");
                int retval = head->val;
                free(head);
                return retval;
            }
            node_t* current = head;
            node_t* next_node = head->next;
            while (next_node->next != NULL) {
                current = current->next;
                next_node = next_node->next;
            }
            int retval = next_node->val;
            free(next_node);
            current->next = NULL;
            return retval;
        }
        printf("Cannot remove from NULL.");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    //removeAtStart
    int removeAtStart(node_t** head) {
        if (*head) {
            if ((*head)->next == NULL) {
                printf("WARNING: Removing the list's only element. Further use of this list's identifier will result in unintended effects.");
            }
            int retval = (*head)->val;
            node_t* next_node = (*head)->next;
            free(*head);
            *head = next_node;
            return retval;
        }
        printf("Cannot remove from NULL.");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    //removeAtIndex
    int removeAtIndex(node_t** head, int n) {
        if (*head) {
            if (n == 0) {
                return removeAtStart(head);
            }
            int i;
            node_t* previous = *head;
            node_t* to_remove = (*head)->next;
            for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                if (previous->next == NULL) {
                    printf("Index out of range.");
                    exit(1);
                }
                previous = previous->next;
                to_remove = to_remove->next;
            }
            previous->next = to_remove->next;
            int retval = to_remove->val;
            free(to_remove);
            return retval;
        }
        printf("Cannot remove from NULL.");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    //removeByValue
    int removeByValue(node_t** head, int n) {
        if (*head) {
            if ((*head)->val == n) {
                removeAtStart(head);
            }
            node_t* previous = *head;
            node_t* current = (*head)->next;
            while (previous->next != NULL) {
                if (current->val == n) {
                    node_t* to_remove = current;
                    previous->next = current->next;
                    free(to_remove);
                    return n;
                }
                previous = previous->next;
                current = current->next;
            }
            return NULL;
        }
        printf("Cannot remove from NULL.");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    //deleteList
    void deleteList(node_t** head) {
        if (*head) {
            while ((*head)->next != NULL) {
                removeAtStart(head);
            }
            removeAtStart(head);
            return;
        }
        printf("Cannot delete empty list.");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    //tests
    int main() {
        node_t* my_list = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        if (my_list) { my_list->val = 1; my_list->next = NULL; }
        printList(my_list);
    
        //add to list
        int i;
        for (i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
            addAtEnd(my_list, i);
        }
        printList(my_list);
    
        //add to start
        addAtStart(&my_list,0);
        printList(my_list);
    
        //add at index
        addAtIndex(&my_list, 10, 0);
        addAtIndex(&my_list, 10, 6);
        addAtIndex(&my_list, 10, 12);
        printList(my_list);
    
        //remove from end
        removeAtEnd(my_list);
        printList(my_list);
        
        //remove from start
        removeAtStart(&my_list);
        printList(my_list);
    
        //remove at index
        removeAtIndex(&my_list, 0);
        printList(my_list);
        removeAtIndex(&my_list, 4);
        printList(my_list);
    
        //remove by value (first instance)
        removeByValue(&my_list, 1);
        printList(my_list);
        removeByValue(&my_list, 5);
        printList(my_list);
        removeByValue(&my_list, 9);
        printList(my_list);
    
        //delete list
        deleteList(&my_list);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I looked at the first few lines of your code, I noticed that the code is reasonably concise and well written. That's what motivated me to go ahead and take the time to review all the rest as well.

I'll start right from the top.  Before starting the review, I just quickly glanced over the whole code, without reading carefully. Therefore, the following notes may be what a random first-time reader of your code thinks.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

That's a nice start, clean and simple. The standard headers are sorted alphabetically, as usual. I cannot say whether you did this intentionally since there are only 2 headers at all, which amounts for a 50:50 chance.

```c
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node* next;
} node_t;
```

Also clean and simple. You probably noticed that the standard C library provides many types named `something_t`, therefore you followed this pattern. In general, following existing practice is a good idea. For your own type names, you should choose a different pattern though. I don't think that any future C standard will define and reserve the name `node_t`, but still the type names ending in `_t` are an indicator that the type name comes from the Standard C Library or from POSIX.

You can even choose `node` as the type name. Then you have both `struct node` and plain `node`. This is no problem at all since these two names live in completely separate namespaces and won't influence each other. (Well, [unless you use JetBrain's CLion](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-22498), but that's a bug in CLion.)

```c
//printList
void printList(node_t* head) {
```

There is no need to repeat the function name in a comment. If you want to have more than 1 empty line between function definitions, just use 2 empty lines here. That's what the Python Style Guide PEP8 considers good style, and it makes sense for C as well.

If you describe the purpose of the function `printList` to another human, you will notice that the description sounds quite weird when you say:

> `printList` takes a *list node* and prints all elements until the end.

It just doesn't match that the function is called "do something with a list" but then doesn't take a "list" as its parameter, but a "list node".

For singly linked lists, the list as a whole and the list node can be represented using the same underlying data type. Still, for human readers it's good to distinguish them.

I would prefer to define a list type as well:

```c
typedef struct {
    node_t *head;
} int_list;
```

Using this type, the function definition would become:

```c
void printList(int_list *list);
```

Granted, the word "list" appears quite often, but that's ok.

Next topic. Since the function `printList` is not supposed to modify the list, you can declare this using the keyword `const`:

```c
void printList(const int_list *list);
```

This `const` doesn't make your code fool-proof though. It is mostly a hint to human readers. The compiler will prevent you from assigning to `list->head`, but assigning to `list->head->val` is still allowed since the keyword `const` only applies to a single `->`, not to all of them.

Continuing with your original code:

```c
void printList(node_t* head) {
    if (head) {
        node_t* current = head;
        while (current != NULL) {
```

You have two places where you test whether a pointer is `NULL` or not. For `head` the compiler inserts the `!= NULL` implicitly, and for `current`, you wrote the `!= NULL` yourself. This is inconsistent. Choose either style and apply it consistently. I prefer to write the `!= NULL` explicitly, since that allows me to communicate to the human reader the following cases:

```c
    if (cond)
    if (character != '\0')
    if (integer != 0)
    if (floating != 0.0)
    if (pointer != NULL)
```

As you can see, there are several ways to write a zero. Omitting the `!= 0` is shorter, for sure, but also makes the code ambiguous for human readers.

> “Programs are meant to be read by humans and only incidentally for computers to execute.”
>
> ― Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs

The main part of `printList` looks fine. But the end surprised me:

```c
    printf("Cannot print an empty list.");
    exit(1);
```

Why can the program not print an empty list? That's the easiest task of all.

Continuing to the next function, `addAtEnd`.

```c
void addAtEnd(node_t* head, int val) {
    if (head) {
        node_t* current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        if (current->next) {
            current->next->next = NULL;
            current->next->val = val;
        }
        return;
```

Before this `return`, if `current->next` is `NULL`, the memory could not be allocated. That is a surprising situation since the function's name promises that it adds something to the list, yet in this case it doesn't add anything. Even worse, there is no efficient way for the caller to test whether something was added or not. Therefore, it should be an error if memory allocation fails.

There are many programs that wrap `malloc` in a simple fail-fast `xmalloc` function:

```c
void *xmalloc(size_t n)
{
    void *ptr = malloc(n);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "xmalloc: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Continuing with the rest of `addAtEnd`:

```c
    printf("Cannot add to NULL.");
    exit(1);
```

This error message shows that you chose the wrong data type for the function parameter. Currently you pass `node_t *head`. But like in `addAtStart` below, you should make that a `node_t **`, so you can modify the passed in list head. Or use the `int_list` type I suggested above.

The next function is `addAtStart`:

```c
    printf("Cannot add to NULL.");
    exit(1);
```

Why not? Just assign `*head = new_node`, and you're done.

With all these error messages, I wonder how you add the first node to the list at all. Therefore I peeked to the `main` function and saw immediately that you cheated there. You added the first node by directly manipulating the members of `struct node`. That's exactly what you should not do. Accessing the struct members is the job of the functions `addAtEnd` and `addAtFront`.

```c
void addAtIndex(node_t** head, int val, int n) {
```

The name `n` is often used for "the number of things", "the total", "the size", "the count". You are using it for an index here. You should rather use the name "index" here. If you are programming on a system [with a predefined function of that same name](https://man.netbsd.org/index.3), you can abbreviate the name to `idx`, which is common.

```c
    printf("Index out of bounds.");
    exit(1);
```

Detecting out of bounds access is good programming style. You could additionally add the failed index to the error message, that's exactly what `printf` is for:

```c
    printf("Index %d out of bounds.", idx);
```

The next function is `removeAtEnd`.

```c
    if (head) {
        if (head->next == NULL) {
            printf("WARNING: Removing the list's only element. Further use of this list's identifier will result in unintended effects.");
```

That's bad. The very basic concept of a list is that it is either empty or contains some elements. The simplest definition of a list is "either empty or a tuple consisting of (head, tail), where tail is a list".

By forbidding an empty list, you are removing almost all usefulness from the code.

I'm skipping a few functions now, which are similar to the above functions. Over to the main function.

```c
int main() {
    node_t* my_list = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
```

That's bad code. The function `main` is not supposed to know how a list is represented in memory. You should define a function `newList` that hides the implementation detail.

```c
    if (my_list) { my_list->val = 1; my_list->next = NULL; }
```

As I already said above, you are cheating here. You should really allow lists to be empty.

The test code looks well-designed and obvious.

```c
    //remove by value (first instance)
    removeByValue(&my_list, 1);
    printList(my_list);
    removeByValue(&my_list, 5);
    printList(my_list);
    removeByValue(&my_list, 9);
    printList(my_list);
```

In the above lines, you should add test code that removes a value that occurs several times in the list. And you should add test code that tries to remove a value that the list doesn't contain.

In summary, there are many small places to improve. But the overall design of defining short functions with good descriptive names is something you did really well, and that's usually the most crucial part. When I write code, I heavily rely on the names of functions, types and variables.

So far for now. When you have updated your code (locally on your computer, not in this question), feel free to post a follow-up question with the updated code, referring to this question. There are some more things to cover, but that would have become too much for now. :)

If you want to compare your list code to mine, I'm maintaining [this header](https://github.com/NetBSD/src/blob/trunk/usr.bin/make/lst.h) and [implementation](https://github.com/NetBSD/src/blob/trunk/usr.bin/make/lst.c) of a doubly-linked list. You will notice that I didn't implement `addAtIndex` and `removeAtIndex` since I don't need them and they are inefficient for linked lists.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> typedef struct node {
>     int val;
>     struct node* next;
> } node_t;
> ```

Be careful with names - POSIX reserves all identifiers ending in `_t`, so there's potential for a clash here.

---

> ```
>     printf("Cannot add to NULL.");
>     exit(1);
> ```

It's good to see some error checking.  But some problems with this:

- Output should be complete lines (ending with `\n`)
- We should be using the standard error stream, not standard output
- We need a way to disable the printing
- We don't want to `exit()` from an inner function like this, if the calling code could handle it better.

---

Similarly, look at this error checking:

> ```
>     if (*head) {
>         node_t* new_node = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
>         if (new_node) {
>             new_node->next = *head;
>             new_node->val = val;
>         }
>         *head = new_node;
>         return;
>     }
> ```

It's good that we handle getting a null pointer from `malloc()`.  But what happens when we do?  We replace `head` with that null pointer, and leave no way to access or release the previous pointer that was there.

We could implement the list a little differently to avoid the need for a non-null `head` element - have a think about how we could do that.

---

> ```
>             node_t* new_node = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
> ```

Because `malloc()` returns a `void*`, which can be assigned to any other kind of object pointer in C, there's no need for that cast.  It's actually harmful, because it clutters the code, and could mask a failure to properly declare `malloc` (i.e. failing to `#include <stdlib.h>`).

Many of us consider good style to write

```
            node_t* new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node);
```

The application of `sizeof` to the dereferenced variable (rather than the type) can be more clearly seen to be the correct size when it's used in an assignment rather than an initialization:

```
        current->next = malloc(sizeof *current->next);
```

---

Tests are better if they are *self-checking*.  What we have:

> ```
>     //remove from end
>     removeAtEnd(my_list);
>     printList(my_list);
>     
>     //remove from start
>     removeAtStart(&my_list);
>     printList(my_list);
> ```

requires inspection and interpretation of the outputs.  What we really want is a test program that exits with non-zero status if any of the tests fail.

> ```
>     assert(equal_elements(my_list, 4, {2,3,4,5}));
>
>     //remove from end
>     removeAtEnd(my_list);
>     assert(equal_elements(my_list, 3, {2,3,4}));
>     
>     //remove from start
>     removeAtStart(&my_list);
>     assert(equal_elements(my_list, 3, {3,4}));
> ```

There are more sophisticated techniques than `assert()`, which can show actual and expected values at each failure - look up **unit-test frameworks** in your favourite online encyclopaedia!

Answer (score 3):

**Am I treating errors, exit codes, and warning messages appropriately?**

**1)**
I see there is one warning from function `removeByValue`

> warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

`int removeByValue(node_t** head, int n) {` returns `int`, but you are returning `NULL` after the `while` loop, which is not required.

Also, for the below snippet,

```
int removeByValue(node_t** head, int n) {
    
    if (*head) {
        if ((*head)->val == n) {
            removeAtStart(head);
        }
        
    /* the rest of your code */
    
    exit(1);
}
```

you should return after `removeAtStart(head);` else it will continue with the next set of statements which is not required.

Check all functions once for the same comment.

**2)**
The below print is not really required in `removeAtStart` function,  because it is possible that list can be empty, so just check head is `NULL` or not, then print either list is empty or list elements.

```
printf("WARNING: Removing the list's only element. Further use of this list's identifier will result in unintended effects.");
```

**3)**
Also, use `if-else` conditions to test `true` / `false` scenarios, to avoid empty `return` statement.

```
//printList
void printList(node_t* head) {
    if (head) {
        node_t* current = head;
        while (current != NULL) {
            printf("%d\n", current->val);
            current = current->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("Cannot print an empty list.");
    exit(1);
}
```

`printList` can be better written as:

```
void printList(node_t* head) {
    
    if (head) {
        node_t* current = head;
        while (current != NULL) {
            printf("%d ", current->val);
            current = current->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf("Cannot print an empty list.");
    }
}
```

**4)**
Functions `addAtEnd`, `addAtStart` both uses `malloc` to create new nodes and then use, it's kind of redundant functionality.

Better write a function such as `node_t* createNode(int data)` or `node_t* createNode(void)` which internally just uses `malloc` to create a new node and assigns data (in case first method is used).

I personally prefer `node_t* createNode(int data)`

```
node_t* createNode(int data){
    node_t* newNode = NULL;
    // allocate memory for newNode
    newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);
    // check allocation is OK
    if(newNode){
        // store data
        newNode->val = data;
        // make next as NULL
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }
    // finally return newNode
    return newNode;
}
```

**Is this code allocating and freeing memory in a responsible manner?**

**5)**
There is a problem in `removeAtEnd` and `removeAtIndex`

```
//removeAtEnd  
int removeAtEnd(node_t* head) {
    if (head) {
        if (head->next == NULL) {
            printf("WARNING: Removing the list's only element. Further use of this list's identifier will result in unintended effects.");
            int retval = head->val;
            free(head);
            return retval;
        }
```

In the function `removeAtEnd` the changes you are doing to `head` are not reflected to your main function because they are local to `removeAtEnd`.

When you do `free(head);` in `removeAtEnd` your `head` will be free of allocated memory, but in the `main` function the `head` ptr will still point to same location and accessing `head` after this function will yield you undefined results.

What you should do is:

```
if (head->next == NULL) {
    printf("WARNING: Removing the list's only element. Further use of this list's identifier will result in unintended effects.");
    int retval = head->val;
    free(head);
    //either do this
    //head = NULL;
    //return head;

    // or do this
    return NULL;
```

The signature of your `removeAtEnd` should be changed to `node_t* removeAtEnd(..)`

**6)**
`removeAtIndex` when you traverse using `previous` and `to_remove` you are not checking whether `previous` is NULL or  `to_remove` is `NULL`.

Below statement may cause your program to crash in case if there are less number of nodes than the passed index `n`.

```
previous = previous->next;
to_remove = to_remove->next;
```

In addition to checking your index is less than `n` also check for `previous` and
`to_remove` pointer for `NULL`.

**General Comments:**

- In your `main` function all of the functions you are calling are not collecting any return value, though they are returning some value.
- You should always collect the return value from functions and handle appropriately
- Get rid of `exit()` function in all places and use proper return value and handle that in caller.
- You can also think of implementing a menu-driven program using `do-while` and `switch`.

Comment: I doubt that calling `exit` can produce a memory leak.

Comment: @RolandIllig, not in all cases, just image if `malloc` is used before a calling a function which is using `exit`, if in the function `exit()` is hit then how can we free the memory allocated before the function call?

Comment: Freeing the memory after `exit` is called is not the task of the program anymore. That has to be done by the hosting C implementation.

Comment: @RolandIllig, Got it, Corrected memory-leaks sentence, thanks for the point.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to be expandable and utilized by future programs, migrating some of the code to an implementation C file would be apt and conventional. To utilize your program you would simply make a reference using the `#include` preprocessor directive.

Your testing methods are simple but are prone to human error for obvious reasons. One method I see working is using a simple hash function to compare digests of lists. Concatenate the entire list to a string of numbers. This way you can compare massive lists at considerable speed. A simple implementation of Java's `hashCode()` function would be a great option. A link to the documentation is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29

> Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a String object is computed as
> s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29)*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
> using int arithmetic, where s[i] is the ith character of the string, n is the length of > the string, and ^ indicates exponentiation. (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)

This implementation can also be used to see if your deleteList(..) function is functional, because the hash of an empty string (list, in this case) is 0.

Comment: Java's hashCode() function is only for use when assigning bins in a hashtable. You can't use a 32-bit hash to accurately compare two objects - there's way too much chance for collisions (i.e. two different strings giving the same value of the hashcode). Java itself does not use hashCode() in its equals() implementation.
Also, calculating the String.hashCode() in Java is basically as complex as just comparing all the characters in two strings.